# Does the Monk passive skill Unity stack with multiple Monks applying it?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

Unity currently reads: "Each ally affected by your Mantras increases your damage by 5%, up to a maximum of 20%, and has 5% increased damage."

Let's say you're with 4 allies, at least one of which is a Monk. You get +20% from your Unity. Do you also get +5% from theirs (since maybe these are considered separate buffs)?

If there are multiple other Monks, would you get multiple +5%s? (my understanding of buffs is that no, you would only get 1 in this case)

Answer (score 1):

From the ability description it appears that this only works with one other Monk. You can only affect 3 of your allies (since you are the fourth player.) You can't have four allies. Therefore, you would only ever get a 15% damage buff from them. The last 5% would then have to come from another Monk's Unity buff maxing you (and them) out at a 20% boost.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this passive registers the player receiving all 4 mantra's, and same mantra's do no stack, so stacking 4-pc with 4 monks would not work, the team would only receive the first applied of each mantra.